# Can templates (with slot behavior) and the shadow DOM be used on non-custom elements?

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom, html-templates

Given that Web Components defines custom elements, templates, and shadow DOM separately, can templates (including slot behavior) be used on non-custom elements such as elements creating on the fly for which one doesn't wish to go to the trouble of defining a reusable custom element? And can one-off elements have their shadow DOM altered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. adding (a copy of) the template's contents to a (one-off) element's
shadow root will fill the template's slots based on the one-off element's
children (e.g., any of the children which have a `slot` attribute) as
would be the case if you had instead defined the one-off element as a
custom element.

```
<template id="t">
    <slot name="h">NEED NAME</slot>
    <h2>Heading level 2</h2>
    <slot>OTHER CONTENT</slot>
</template>

<div id="myElem">
    <h1 slot="h">Heading level 1</h1>
    <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>

<script>
    const $ = (s) => document.querySelector(s);
    const myElem = $('#myElem');
    const shadowRoot = myElem.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.appendChild($('#t').content.cloneNode(true));
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fL2wwmh/1/)

This will effectively render as the following for `myElem` (though it will not be in the DOM as such):

```
<div id="myElem">
    <h1>Heading level 1</h1>
    <h2>Heading level 2</h2>
    <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
```

This is called the element's "flattened DOM tree".

For an example with styling as well, see [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efy0rtk0/)